# Fetching questions with a tag from Stack Overflow

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a small group of developers under my Discord server and I want to help people find solutions for their problem in Stack Overflow.
How can I make a bot collect the last question with a specific tag and send it in a message on Discord?

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow has everything described in the docs: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions

Example call here would be:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow&tagged=python
if you want to fetch questions from `stackoverflow` and tagged with `python`

Everything you need to do is make simple REST call to this URL

Comment: In fact where i can put that url resource under Discord ? do i need to develop my own rebot ?